# Sql want to get matching plus new records from tables

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL queries, I have tables:

**Table1**:

```
Id  | Flag
----+------
200 | 1
201 | 1
202 | 1
203 | 1
204 | 1
```

**Table2**:

```
Id  | Flag
----+------
200 | 0
203 | 1
```

I want result like this:

```
Id  | Flag
----+------
200 | 0
201 | 1
202 | 1
204 | 1
```

I have tried with left join but still I am not getting expected result.

Comment: Please explain the logic, particularly for filtering out "3".

Comment: I have main table and audit table, I want to get records who's value has been changed from main table and any newly added records from main table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want a join where the `Flag` value from `TableB` is given priority over the value from `TableA` *and* where the `Flag` values do not match in both tables.

If that is the case, you could accomplish this with the use of a [`COALESCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as well as a `WHERE` condition to remove items where the join fails and the matching `Flag` values):

```
SELECT     a.ID,
           COALESCE(b.Flag, a.Flag) Flag
FROM       TableA a
LEFT JOIN  TableB b
ON         a.ID = b.ID
AND        (b.Flag IS NULL OR a.Flag <> b.Flag)
```

### Example

You can [see an interactive working example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9b4791/16), which given your data outputs the expected values:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But also getting 203 in this case. I should not get 203 as it has same value in both tables.

Comment: You'll just need to specify when the join fails (e.g. b.Flag IS NULL) and when the Flags do not match (e.g. a.Flag <> b.Flag). I've updated the answer and example accordingly.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want all rows except for the ones with "1" in both `flag` columns.  Then, if available you want the flag in `table2`.

If this is a correct interpretation:

```
select t1.id, coalesce(t2.flag, t1.flag)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.flag <> 1 or
      (t2.flag is null or t2.flag <> 1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cfdb2a745917082d22fbd8d41a98d012) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Only getting values with flag = 0

Comment: @revolutionNET . . . I added a db<>fiddle to demonstrate that the logic works.